# Padding bottom equals to 100% in CSS

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to make a responsive square in CSS, I wrote the following HTML for the same.

```css
.square-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="square-container">
  <img class="content" src="https://static.toiimg.com/photo/48553824/.jpg">
</div>
```

This code is working perfectly. But I have a doubt, how is the height of child element that is img in this case is effected by `padding-bottom` of parent element.

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: the padding-bottom is setting the height of the parent to keep the ratio and the image which is out of the flow is using that height (note the height:100%)